# Access server-side middleware for each page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3

I want to create a global server middleware that works on every page.

I used the code below in Nuxt 2

```
// nuxt2
export default async (payload) => {
  try {
    const { app, req } = payload;
  }
  if (process.server) {
    // logic
  }
}
```

If include the word 'global' in the file name, it will work on the client side for every page, but it will not work on the server side.

```
export default async (to, from) => {
  try {
    let isServer, req, path;
    const serverContext = useNuxtApp().ssrContext;
    const event = useRequestEvent();
    console.log(event, serverContext);
}
```

then  `useRequestEvent` `useNuxtApp().ssrContext` is are undefined when i routing page

How can I access the context with events for each page on the server side as well?

I access the context with events for each page on the server side as well

```
export default async (to, from) => {
  try {
    let isServer, req, path;
    const serverContext = useNuxtApp().ssrContext;
    const event = useRequestEvent();
    console.log(event, serverContext);
}

// console
// [event Object, serverContext object]
```